How to Download Files from Redmine Redmine/Documents/xxx Links Programmatically
I am using the following code that works ok in order to download links to Attachments for links of this type: https://myredminehost/redmine/attachments/3164
var optionsBuilder = new RedmineManagerOptionsBuilder();
optionsBuilder.WithHost(RedmineHost);
optionsBuilder.WithApiKeyAuthentication(apiKey); 
var rm = new RedmineManager(optionsBuilder);
var attchmt = await rm.GetAsync<Attachment>(id);
var fileBytes = await rm.DownloadFileAsync(attchmt.ContentUrl);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, fileBytes);

However, after investigating for several hours, I still can't download the files for this type of link: https://myredminehost/redmine/documents/785
How could I download the files for this type of link (documents)?
Thank you in advance,
